# How would the Heimlich maneuver or CPR be done in weightlessness?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, safety

[Abdominal Thrusts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdominal_thrusts) (the "Heimlich maneuver") and [Cardiopulmonary Resuscitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiopulmonary_resuscitation) (CPR) are life-saving [first aid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_aid) procedures that involve  carefully targeted manual forcing of a victims body in order to dislodge an obstruction that is preventing breathing, or to move oxygenated blood in the case of heart failure.

When done properly, both of these depend upon working against gravity to generate sufficient force.

Have procedures been developed to do these in weightlessness?

[image]

**above:** Illustration of [Abdominal Thrusts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdominal_thrusts) (the "Heimlich maneuver"), from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:AbdominalThrust_HeimlichManoeuvre.svg)

[image]

**above:** Demonstration of [Cardiopulmonary Resuscitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiopulmonary_resuscitation) (CPR) on a simulated patient, from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CPR_training-04.jpg)

Comment: Relevant: https://humanresearchroadmap.nasa.gov/Evidence/medicalConditions/Choking_Obstructed_Airway.pdf

Comment: We monitor humans very carefully before sending them to them to space. Prevention is the best medicine :-). Moreover, CPR alone is usually not enough (i believe <10% success rate; i can try to source that) CPR is mostly done to preserve the body as much as possible while better tools/medicine are on the way.

Comment: @Antzi Monitoring is a good stop-gap for most situations that might require CPR, but the Heimlich is often required in situations for which you can't monitor in advance.

Comment: I don't see an issue with the Heimlich - the victim is between the rescuer and the rescuer's hands - no external force needed . CPR is harder, but I suspect there would be an AED available to defibrillate/restart the heart.

Comment: @JonCuster apparently NASA did not se an issue with CPR in 2001 either (according to manual shown in OrganicMarble's answer) but not seeing a problem does not mean there isn't one. There must be some reasons that training for abdominal thrusts instructs you to stand the victim up first. Also if you are alone there are variants that use gravity and a chair. Let's wait for an authoritative answer instead of performing *first aid speculation*.

Comment: @Antzi *cardiac arrest* can happen for many different reasons. If someone were deprived of oxygen due to a spacesuit failure, I believe CPR would be performed as soon as possible. Other medical emergencies can result in cardiac arrest as well. Carrie-Anne Moss saved Val Kylmer's life at the end of the movie *The Red Planet* by performing CPR shown in this scene https://youtu.be/UNl72oAz8F0?t=27. Yes that's a movie and it may not be so accurate ;) but the point is that CPR *in certain key situations that might occur in space* is probably more effective than the overall 10% you are suggesting.

Comment: @uhoh - While having a choking victim standing up is preferred for the Heimlich (mainly because the natural response will involve the dislodged object exiting and falling away from the throat), it is not required. If the victim has passed out and you have placed them (gently one hopes) on the ground, you don't get to just say 'too bad' - you have to do the thrusts on a prone patient. In space, with no gravity, well you get neither the plus of gravity helping for a standing victim, nor the minus of having to lie them down on the floor for an unconscious one.

Comment: @JonCuster if you can supply an authoritative answer, please do! If this can ruled out as being an issue in weightlessness, then a short answer to that effect would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why, by the [checklist](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwighJS24K7UAhUO9GMKHdwKDpQQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nasa.gov%2Fcenters%2Fjohnson%2Fpdf%2F163533main_ISS_Med_CL.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGusAle_m4FVnEM4o6fl2hScb4orA&sig2=Z6GeMzTipXYMQSrbstHLUw), of course:

[[image]]

[image]

The Heimlich maneuver is referred to, but not described, i.e. "perform Heimlich maneuver", so it must be standard.

Comment: It doesn't specify how one is supposed to get the proper leverage to do this procedure. Is that given via verbal instruction?

Comment: The very first thing is restraining the patient with bungees.

Comment: That explains how you keep the patient immobile, but how does the person administering aid apply pressure to the chest?

Comment: I assume they attach themselves with bungees or foot restraints or whatever they normally use to perform actions that require them to be restrained.

Comment: That was my assumption as well, I was just surprised to find that it wasn't documented. I guess it's standard enough that it's not worthy of mention.

Comment: There's a lot of interesting stuff in that checklist. Like BEHAVORIAL- SUICIDIAL -EMERGENCY

Comment: Is this 2001 manual and its images the most recent version, or have there been updates as the've figured this out? I heard something about this on the radio last night, found it here this morning; http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p05597y6 **update:** http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-4573096/Experts-reveal-perform-aid-space.html please consider adding some of this!

Comment: It is the only full ISS MED checklist released to the public that I am aware of. The actual document is of course a working NASA document that continues to be updated, but those updates have not been released.

Comment: There should be a picture showing how to restrain the patient and the helper.